# Python encoding issue when trying to parse JSON tweets

Tags: python, json, twitter

I am trying to parse out the tweet and username sections of the JSON object returned from Twitter using the following code:

```
class listener(StreamListener):

  def on_data(self, data):
          all_data = json.loads(data)
          tweet = all_data["text"]
          username = all_data["user"]["screen_name"]

          c.execute("INSERT INTO tweets (tweet_time, username, tweet) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)" ,
                    (time.time(), username, tweet))
          print (username, tweet)
          return True

  def on_error(self, status):
      print (status)

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track = ["LeBron James"])
```

But I get the following error. How can the code be adjusted to decode or encode the response properly?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/sagars/PycharmProjects/YouTube NLP Lessons/Twitter Stream to DB.py", line 45, in <module>
    twitterStream.filter(track = ["LeBron James"])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 428, in filter
    self._start(async)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 346, in _start
    self._run()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 286, in _run
    raise exception
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 255, in _run
    self._read_loop(resp)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 309, in _read_loop
    self._data(next_status_obj)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 289, in _data
    if self.listener.on_data(data) is False:
  File "C:/Users/sagars/PycharmProjects/YouTube NLP Lessons/Twitter Stream to DB.py", line 36, in on_data
    print (username, tweet)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-8: character maps to <undefined>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the problem with that is the information you get from twitter is not `utf-8` encoded, which is causing you to get the `charmap` error. To fix that, you'll need to encode it.

```
tweet = all_data["text"].encode('utf-8')
username = all_data["user"]["screen_name"].encode('utf-8')
```

This will cause you to lose some of emoji and special characters that show up in the tweet, it will be converted to `\x899`. If you really need that information (I discard it myself) for sentiment analysis, then you'll need to install a package with a pre-compiled list to convert them accordingly.